# Evaluation of $\sum_{i=1}^n\cfrac{\beta_i^k}{\prod_{j=1\\j\neq i}^n (\beta_j-\beta_i)}$

Tags: summation, products

Trying to solve a problem I ended up working on a polynomial of degree $n-1$ in $t$, $p(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k t^k$, whose coefficients are given by

$a_k=\sum_{i=1}^n\cfrac{\beta_i^k}{\prod_{j=1\\j\neq i}^n (\beta_j-\beta_i)}$

Here, $\beta_i$ are $n$ distinct positive and ordered real numbers, so that $0<\beta_1<\beta_2<\cdots<\beta_n$. What can I say about the coefficients $a_k$? I made some attempts and I think that

$a_k=\begin{cases}0 &k=0,\dots,n-2\\z\neq0 &k=n-1\end{cases}$

but I don't know if this is true, how to prove it and what $z$ would be. Do any of you know a solution or a reference for this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Could you include the calculations in the specific case $n=3$ for the $a_k$ values?

Comment: How could the result come out $z$ in some case, when no $z$ appears in the definition of $a_k$?

Comment: I wrote $z$ to indicate an unknown. I'm sorry if it was unclear: what I meant is the only non-zero coefficient would be $a_n$. I'll try writing down the calculations for the $n=3$ case.

Comment: Yes, I'd be curious to see how terms cancel when $k=1,2$ for the $n=3$ case of the expression.

Comment: Suppose $m=2$ and $n=3$. Then

$a_0=\cfrac{1}{(\beta_2-\beta_1)(\beta_3-\beta_1)}+\cfrac{1}{(\beta_1-\beta_2)(\beta_3-\beta_2)}+\cfrac{1}{(\beta_1-\beta_3)(\beta_2-\beta_3)}$
$=\cfrac{\beta_3-\beta_2-\beta_3+\beta_1+\beta_2-\beta_1}{(\beta_3-\beta_2)(\beta_3-\beta_1)(\beta_2-\beta_1)}=0$

Comment: $a_1=\cfrac{\beta_1}{(\beta_2-\beta_1)(\beta_3-\beta_1)}+\cfrac{\beta_2}{(\beta_1-\beta_2)(\beta_3-\beta_2)}+\cfrac{\beta_3}{(\beta_1-\beta_3)(\beta_2-\beta_3)}$
$=\cfrac{\beta_1(\beta_3-\beta_2)-\beta_2(\beta_3-\beta_1)+\beta_3(\beta_2-\beta_1)}{(\beta_3-\beta_2)(\beta_3-\beta_1)(\beta_2-\beta_1)}=0$

Comment: In your description there is reference to $m,$ the degree of $p(t).$ However the definition of $a_k$ only refers to the $n$ points $\beta_j$ and the power $k.$ If one allows larger $m$ then the value of $k$ would not be restricted by that $m.$ Would that case have interest, or would it not be appropriate in your application?

Comment: The degree $m$ of the polynomial and the number $n$ of points $\beta_i$ are a priori not related, so I can take $m$ to be as large as I want.

Comment: Please have a look at what I have added to my answer, which IMP shows your conjecture mentioned in comments is indeed true. Let me know if you want some detail.

Comment: These properties of the Vandermonde matrix seem relevant indeed, and your solution could make the trick. From the product $S_f \det(V_n)$ onwards, though, I have some problems following it, so yeah if you could provide some more details or reference on these properties it would be useful. In the meantime, thank you very much.

Comment: I'll make some more explanation soon (a bit busy now for finals where I teach...)

Comment: Hey! No worries, I think I've figured out all the steps now, thank you again. Only thing you should probably add (if you want to edit your final answer), is that when you compute the determinant of the "modified" $V_n$ (i.e. the Vandermonde matrix with last row given by $[f(\beta_1),\dots,f(\beta_n)]$) by expanding the last row there is a $(-1)^{n-1}$ missing. This indeed gives $a_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}$, which for example can be easily checked for the $n=2$ case.

Comment: The signs $\pm 1$ come from the number of sign reversals in the denominator product in your expression needed to put each difference in "decreasing order" as e.g. $\beta_4-\beta_3,$ to make things ready for multiplication by the Vandermonde matrix determinant. In fact if a few cases are worked out, it is *exactly* the modified Vandermonde determinant [no sign change at last row] which is relevant. Note that in expanding across row $n$ the sign at position $(n,k)$ is $(-1)^{n+k}$...

Comment: I think on the left hand side the signs depend only on $i$, while on the right hand side they depend on both $i$ and $n$. Specifically, if my calculations are correct, I found
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \cfrac{f(\beta_i)}{\prod_{j=1\\j\neq i}^n(\beta_j-\beta_i)}=\\
\cfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}f(\beta_i)\prod_{1\le k<j\le n\\k\neq i}(\beta_j-\beta_k)}{\prod_{1\le i<j\le n}(\beta_j-\beta_i)}
\end{align*}
while if you expand $V_n^{(f)}$ across row $n$ you find
\begin{align*}\det(V_n^{(f)})=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{n+i}f(\beta_i)\prod_{1\le k<j\le n\\k\neq i}(\beta_j-\beta_k)\end{align*}
right?

Comment: I'll have to look at this more carefully. Did you try it on $n=2,3,4$ cases?

Comment: Note that in aligning the differences $(\beta_j-\beta_i)$ the firt $i-1$ differences are already in descending index order, while the remaining $n-i$ are in asending order and so need to be switched, making the sign come out $(-1)^{n-i}=(-1)^{n+i},$ same as in $\det(V_n^{(f)}).$ I just worked things out completely in the cases $n=2,3$ and all matches up. [I did also do $n=4$ case out a few days ago.]

Comment: yeah the reason why I started thinking about the $-1$ is because for $n=2$ you get
\begin{align*}
\cfrac{\beta_1}{\beta_2-\beta_1}+\cfrac{\beta_2}{\beta_1-\beta_2}=-1
\end{align*}

Comment: I thought in your calculation these two fractions should each have the subtractions in the denominators switched... anyway I think if you try writing it all out for the $n-2,3$ cases it should seem convincing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=3$ and for ease of notation let the points be $a,b,c.$ Then under your conjecture, the expression using the power $k=2$ [which satisfies $k \le n-1]$, namely
$$\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{b^2}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\frac{c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)},$$
should be $0.$ However this expression is identically $1,$ after a check on a symbolic algebra calculator.

**Added later:**
Let $f(x)$ be any function, and let $S_f$ denote your expression for $a_k$ but with its numerator $\beta_i^k$ replaced by $f(\beta_i.)$
Also let $V_n$ denote the $n \times n$ Vandermonde matrix, whose $j$-th row is formed by the $(j-1)$th powers of the $\beta_i,$ for $1 \le i \le n.$
The determinant of $V_n$ is then the product of the factors $(\beta_j-\beta_i)$ for $1 \le i<j\le n.$

It can then be shown that he product $S_f \det (V_n)$ is the same as the determinant of the matrix obtained from $V_n$ when its last row is replaced by the row $[f(\beta_1),f(\beta_2),\cdots f(\beta_n.)].$

If we take $f(x)=x^{n-1}$ this shows that $a_{n-1}=1,$ since we now have the original Vandermonde matrix on both sides. And if $0<k<n-1$ we have on the right side the result of taking the Vandermonde matrix and replacing the last row with one of the rows above it, making that determinant zero.

Comment: You're right, I probably messed up things with the indices in my formulation above, but if I adjust them the main question still stands. Let me edit the original question, and sorry for the confusion, I'm trying to figure out the problem..

Comment: So, for my application I could take $m$ to be as large as I want, but my point is that, fixed the numbers $\beta_i$, I want to know what is the first non-zero coefficient $a_k$, and possibly derive its value. In the example $n=3$ we did above my updated conjecture should stand, am I right?

Comment: What would be your updated conjecture re. the first nonzero coefficient $a_k$? Is your conjecture about what the value of the subscript $k$ should be in terms of $n$? If so my example above (with your examples from comments) shows for $n=3$ the first nonzero $a_k$ occurs when $k=2.$ [i.e. "first subscript" is not just $n-1$ in general]

Comment: I think that $a_k=0$ for all $k=0,\dots,n-2$ and the first non-zero coefficient is $a_{n-1}$. This agrees with our example for $n=3$ (as $a_0=0, a_1=0$ and $a_2\neq0$) but I have no idea how to prove that this is a general result.

Comment: Agrees in $n=4$ case, first nonzero coeff is $a_{4-1}=a_3=1.$